# How do you add a placeholder using @Html.NopEditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, nopcommerce

I am trying to add a placeholder to my text field.

I am fairly new with MVC and only been working on it for the pass month.

My code looks like this:

```
 Branch Hours Description: @Html.NopEditorFor(model => model.Description)

 BRHOURID: @Html.NopEditorFor(model => model.BrHourCode)
```

[image]

is it possible to add a place holder for these 2 fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a HTML attribute

```
Branch Hours Description: @Html.NopEditorFor(model => model.Description, new { @placeholder = "Add Your Placeholder Text Here" } })
```

and that should do it for you

Comment: I run into a compile error message when I try to add it 

Html.NopEditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Add Your Placeholder Text Here" } })

Comment: @Str8UpRippin ive just edited the answer, try it again and see how this works for you

Comment: Do u know how to add a linebreak in comments? I was trying to edit my comment

Comment: you cant add a line break, its all just one paragraph

Comment: I tried to do the method u said above after editing it, and I still run into the same compile error message: 
Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Nop.Wca.Core.Model.BranchHours.BranchHoursModel>' does not contain a definition for 'NopEditorFor' and the best extension method overload 'Nop.Web.Framework.HtmlExtensions.NopEditorFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>, bool?)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: is there a reason your using NopEditorFor rather than EditorFor or TextBoxFor?

Comment: its what all the people working on the project are using.

Comment: ok, take it back a step and when you add the comma in after `model.Description` do you get any intelisense?

Comment: I get inteliesnce when I add a comma, I discussed with one of my members and they said I should use your method but with EditorFor